# Ninject: What does it mean to bind something to itself?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

Ninject has the functionality of `self binding` like `Bind<Samurai>().ToSelf();`

I read about this but I don't get the importance or how this can be useful. Any comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

If Ninject finds a object that needs to be created and it has a constructor that has a `Samurai` parameter it does not know how to instantiate it.

But when you use `Bind<Samurai>().ToSelf();` then Ninject knows that a `Samurai` needs to be created to pass to the `Samurai` parameter.

If that binding was not there then ninject didn't know what to pass, for example there might have been a `SamuraiSubClass` type. But by explicitly saying that when Ninject finds a `Samurai` parameter that it needs to create a `Samurai` for that parameter then Ninject knows exactly what to do.

Comment: Why not just explicitly say what to bind Samurai ?

Comment: `Bind<Samurai>().To<Samurai>();` is the same as `Bind<Samurai>().ToSelf();` it just reads better

Comment: Ok I see so it is not just interfaces that you can inject you can also inject concrete types

Comment: Indeed, or abstract classes

Answer (score 3):

I use the .WithConstructorArgument() quite a bit. `Bind<Samurai>().ToSelf().WithConstructorArgument("owner", user);` Just a nice way to provide an object(s) to your Samuari constructor when it is being injected.