# What does Bind<DateTime>().ToSelf() mean?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

In the NinjectModule of one open source program, I found this line:

```
Bind <DateTime>().ToSelf()
```

What is its purpose? Why to put DateTime in a container? What did the author want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

This makes no sense. Getting DateTime from the container gives you an exception:

> Ninject.ActivationException: 'Error activating int No matching
>   bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable. Activation
>   path:
>
> 2) Injection of dependency int into parameter year of constructor of
>   type DateTime
>
> 1) Request for DateTime

In theory there can be another binding in the solution, which binds long to some constant:

```
Bind<long>().ToConstant(1L);
```

So that you would be able to get a datetime from container based on constructor with number of ticks:

```
public DateTime(long ticks)
```

But anyway this would be really bad practice and I can't see any reason for doing so. If your class depends on basic types like datetime, than rather use `ToConstructor` or `WithConstructorArgument` methods.

Answer (score 0):

duplicate:[Ninject: What does it mean to bind something to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23559120/9678775)

```
Bind<DateTime>().ToSelf()
```

is equivalent to

```
Bind<DateTime>().To<DateTime>()
```

Comment: My question is about DateTime, not about ToSelf()